# Extract QueryString value using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following lines in an apache access log

```
/sms/receiveHLRLookup?Ported=No&Status=Success&MSISDN=647930229655&blah
/sms/receiveHLRLookup?Ported=No&Status=Success&MSISDN=647930229656&blah
/sms/receiveHLRLookup?Ported=No&Status=Success&MSISDN=647930229657&blah
/sms/receiveHLRLookup?Ported=No&Status=Success&MSISDN=647930229658&blah
```

and i want to extract the MSISDN value only, so expected output would be

```
647930229655
647930229656
647930229657
647930229658
```

I'm using the following sed command but i can't get it to stop capturing at `&`

```
sed 's/.*MSISDN=\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Try `sed 's/.*MSISDN=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it will try to match as much as possible while trying to honor entire regex expression... you've to find a way to tell that it needs to stop before `&`... depending on single/multiple character, you'd need different ways to handle it.. or even tool with features not available with sed like lookarounds.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sed** solution:

```
sed -E 's/.*&MSISDN=([^&]+).*/\1/' file
```

- `&` - is key/value pair separator in URL syntax, so you should rely on it
- `([^&]+)` - 1st captured group containing any character sequence except `&`
- `\1` - backreference to the 1st captured group

The output:

```
647930229655
647930229656
647930229657
647930229658
```

Comment: @ManseUK, see my explanation

Answer (score 3):

`-o` : means print only matching string not the whole line.
`-P`: To enable `pcre` regex.
`\K`: means ignore everything on the left. But should be part of actual input string.
`\d`: means digit, `+` means one or more digit.

```
grep -oP 'MSISDN=\K\d+' input
647930229655
647930229656
647930229657
647930229658
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=&MSISDN=)\d+' file 
647930229655
647930229656
647930229657
647930229658
```

`-o` option is meant to show only matched output
`-P` option is meant to enable PCRE (Perl Compatible Regex)
`(?<=regex)` this is to enforce positive look behind assertion. You can read more about them over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups). Lookarounds dont consume any characters while matching unlike normal regex. Hence the only matched output you get it `\d+` which is 1 or more digits.

or using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*MSISDN=([0-9]+).*$/\1/' file 
647930229655
647930229656
647930229657
647930229658
```

Comment: @ManseUK added some explanation

Answer (score 2):

Following simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed 's/.*MSISDN=//;s/&.*//'  Input_file
```

Explanation:

`s/.*MSISDN=//`: `s` means substitute `.*MSISDN=` string with `//` NULL in current line.

`;` semi colon tells `sed` that there is 1 more statement to be executed.

`s/&.*//g'`: `s/&.*//` means substitute `&.*` from `&` to everything with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

you can also pipe `cut` to `cut`

```
cut -d '&' -f3 Input_file |cut -d '=' -f2
```